# Split a "big" table to smaller tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I would like to split a "big" table (a lot of columns) to smaller tables every for example 2 columns.

Is there an easy way to do that?

I only have the table here http://jsfiddle.net/xy3UF/4/. And I would like for example split it every 2 columns. As a result I should have a three tables with containing the `#` column and each one containing 2 of the columns from the big table.

Desired output: http://jsfiddle.net/xy3UF/15/

Comment: Your desired output is a little confusing. Please create HTML code for your desired output.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xy3UF/15/

Comment: Do you want an answer specific to this example or an generic answer?

Comment: AI believe a generic answer will be more helpful for others as well..

Comment: @salamis As Yair pointed out in his answer below, you can change your data to an XML file and use that data with several XSLT files you can reference as needed. If you're more reliant on javascript or jquery (which would probably be easier), you should definitely consider adding some class or id attributes in this table. Does your original code include class and id attributes?

Comment: We can add anything we want (classes - ids). The thing is that this data is from the database so it is difficult to use xml and xslt.

Comment: Hmmm, couldn't you assign classes to the columns, clone the table, and then hide the classes based on the table/column class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function split($table, chunkSize) {
  var cols = $("th", $table).length - 1;
  var n = cols / chunkSize;

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     $("<br/>").appendTo("body");
     var $newTable = $table.clone().appendTo("body");
     for (var j = cols + 1; j > 1; j--) {
         if (j + chunkSize - 1 <= chunkSize * i || j > chunkSize * i + 1) {
             $('td:nth-child(' + j + '),th:nth-child(' + j + ')', $newTable).remove();
         }
     }
  }  
}
```

Where `$table` is the table jQuery object, and `chunkSize` is the size of each *split*. In your example, call it as `split($("table"), 2)`. Note that `chunkSize` must evenly divide the number of columns (excluding the first one) for this to work correctly, for example, for a table with 7 columns, the *valid* values for `chunkSize` are 1, 2, and 3.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VFeng/)**.

Comment: You can use `var n = Math.ceil(cols / chunkSize);`, it will split your 6 columns table (excluding the first one) into a 4 and 2 columns table if you do `split($("table"), 4)`

Comment: How would you handle table datas with colspan, I am trying to use this example, but my first 2 rows all the colspans and it messes up all the rows below it as the amount of columns do not match

Answer (score 1):

I made better version of table split function that support fix columns (repeat in all tables) and it waste a lot of time:

```js
function range(start, end) {
  var array = new Array();
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function splitTables($tables, chunkSize, fixCols) {
  $table = $($tables);
  console.log('fixCols :', fixCols);
  fixCols = fixCols || [];
  console.log('fixCols :', fixCols);
  fixCols = fixCols.sort();
  console.log('fixCols :', fixCols);
  //chunkSize -= fixCols.length;
  var rowLength = $('tr:first>*', $table).length;
  console.log('total length:', rowLength);
  var n = Math.ceil(rowLength / chunkSize);
  var bufferTables = [];
  var numberList = range(1, rowLength);

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var colList = fixCols.slice(0);
    //console.log('fixCols :',fixCols);
    //console.log('colList :',colList);
    console.log('numberList :', numberList);
    while (colList.length < chunkSize && numberList.length > 0) {
      var index = numberList.shift();
      console.log(index, colList);
      if (colList.indexOf(index) == -1) {
        colList.push(index);
      }
    }

    console.log('col list:', colList);
    var $newTable = $table.clone(true)
    for (var index = 1;
      (index <= rowLength); index++) {
      if (colList.indexOf(index) == -1) {
        console.log('removing:', index);
        $('tr>:nth-child(' + index + ')', $newTable).hide();
      }
    }
    bufferTables.push($newTable)
  }

  $(bufferTables.reverse()).each(function(i, $el) {
    $('<br/>').insertAfter($table);
    $el.insertAfter($table);
  });
  $table.remove();

}

$(function() {
  $('#sbtn').click(function() {
    splitTables($("#tb"), 3, [1]);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sbtn">Split Table !</button>

<table border="1" id="tb">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
      <td>$500</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>$700</td>
      <td>$600</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>$400</td>
      <td>$500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Work</td>
      <td>$80</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$400</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>$500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks good but it breaks if there are more than one fixed column. Check this on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anmrk/3ak98uzh/

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler:

1. Mark the TR:

   ```
   <tr><td>some</td><!-- SPLITHERE -->
   ```
2. Split the table:

   ```
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<!-- SPLITHERE --\>\s*<\/tr>/i, '</tr></table></div><div class="eachPage"><table class="items">');
   ```

   NOTE: that you have to do innerHTML change on the parent element of that table (body in my example), not the table itself, that would NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

using XSLT you can solve the problem easily.

Please visit here: [Split large table into several smaller tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742099/952310)

Comment: Is there an example for that?

Comment: XSLT is a good suggestion, but this data will need to be converted into a well-formed XML document first.