# Make a new table of every second td in a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an older website responsive but I have some problems with the tables.
this is the code of the table(generated from CMS):

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span>mr. Dende</span></td>
<td><span>mr. Harrolds</span></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td><span>Ambrosiushof 27&nbsp;</span> </td>
<td><span>Africastreet 136</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span>5254 HD&nbsp; Londen&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> </td>
<td><span>5152 MD&nbsp; Rome</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span>T: 893-589 31 51 &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> </td>
<td><span>T: 8973-992 98 10</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span>M: +31 36 18 42 18</span></td>
<td><span>M: +31 68 18 18 19 </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

what I try to accomplish is:

[image]

But if I use:

```
    td {
    display: block;
}
```

it looks like:

[image]

I think jquery is my solution I tried this:

```
$(function () {
    var $mainTable = $("table");
    var splitBy = 3;
    var rows = $mainTable.find("tr").slice(splitBy);
    var $secondTable = $("table").parent().append("<table id='secondTable'><tbody></tbody></table>");
    $secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
    $mainTable.find("tr").slice(splitBy).remove();

});
```

But that doesn't do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the HTML?

Comment: nope it is as I mentioned: generated from CMS

Comment: This may not help since you can't control your HTML, but definitely worth a look - https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php . Note there's a link to the article that walks through the project up top.

Comment: I know that, used it a sometimes but doesn't work for this one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a "big" table to smaller tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080216/split-a-big-table-to-smaller-tables)

Comment: no that's another situation, I can't see my solution in it. maybe someone else does

Comment: @Ferryzijl: What is another situation?? It is an exact solution to your problem. Did you even try it out? You just need to re-work it to adapt to your use-case. See, I have quickly adapted that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/srt0oscg/1/

Comment: @Abhitalks that's right! didn't see that thanks

Comment: @Abhitalks make it an asnwer it was the right one

Comment: @Ferryzijl: Don't worry about the answer. Your problem is solved, that is important. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$('body').append($("table").clone());
$($("table")[0]).find('td:first-child').remove();
$($("table")[1]).find('td:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to this. but I know legacy is suck. It is not good for performance.

If you try this, modify "getRows" method first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clearTbody = function() {
    $("tbody").html("");
  }

  var tbodyHtml = "";

  var getRows = function() {
    //get first tr's td count
    //code here
    return 2; //record 0 to 1
  }
  var rows = getRows();

  var getRecord = function(i) {
    var recordTd = new Array();

    $.each($("tr"), function(idx, val) {
      recordTd.push($(val).children().eq(i));
    });

    return recordTd;
  }


  for (var k = 0; rows > k; k++) {
    var recordTdList = getRecord(k);

    tbodyHtml += "<tr>";
    for (var l = 0; recordTdList.length > l; l++) {
      tbodyHtml += "<td>";
      tbodyHtml += $(recordTdList[l]).html();
      tbodyHtml += "</td>";
    }
    tbodyHtml += "</tr>";

  }

  clearTbody();

  $("tbody").html(tbodyHtml);
});
```

```css
td {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>mr. Dende</span>

      </td>
      <td><span>mr. Harrolds</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Ambrosiushof 27&nbsp;</span> 
      </td>
      <td><span>Africastreet 136</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>5254 HD&nbsp; Londen&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
      </td>
      <td><span>5152 MD&nbsp; Rome</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>T: 893-589 31 51 &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
      </td>
      <td><span>T: 8973-992 98 10</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>M: +31 36 18 42 18</span>

      </td>
      <td><span>M: +31 68 18 18 19 </span>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```