# Move columns of a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move columns of a table around in several hundred webpages that are outside of my control so that they print nicely. I can get to the tables in question easily enough with XPATH, but rearranging them has me stumped. Essentially, I want to rearrange this:

Table:

```
Header1 Header2
data1   data2
```

To this:

Table 1:

```
Header1
data1
```

Table 2:

```
Header2
data2
```

Is this possible?

Or, a simplified view of the existing HTML:

```
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<th>Header1</th>
<th>Header2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

It isn't strictly necessary that these become separate tables, but the `data` portions are just wide enough to fit on a page, so they can't be in the same row.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I have been learning jQuery, and it looks like I could use something like this:

```
function jqsplit($table, chunkSize) {
  var cols = $("th", $table).length;
  var n = cols / chunkSize;

  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
     $("<br/>").appendTo("body");
     var $newTable = $table.clone().appendTo("body");
     for (var j = cols; j > 0; j--) {
         if (j + chunkSize - 1 <= chunkSize * i || j > chunkSize * i + 1) {
             $('td:nth-child(' + j + '),th:nth-child(' + j + ')', $newTable).remove();
         }
     }
  }  
}
```

(Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080216/split-a-big-table-to-smaller-tables), but modified for my particular use case.)

The problem I now have is that I can't figure out how to select my initial table with jquery, and if I can process them all together. The original tables always have 2 rows and 3 columns, and no other tables match that criteria, can anyone help?

Comment: If anyone wants to neaten my answer up, and it works, i'll mark their solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Solved it. My solution is inelegant as all hell, but works perfectly. Awful code, away!

```
function jqsplit($table, chunkSize) {
    //Splits these specific tables into 3 by creating 3 copies and deleting the unneeded rows.
    var $randomP = $("<p></p>").insertAfter($table);
    var $newTable1 = $table.clone().appendTo($randomP);
    var $newTable2 = $table.clone().appendTo($randomP);
    var $newTable3 = $table.clone().appendTo($randomP);
    $newTable1.children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").get(2).remove();
    $newTable1.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").get(2).remove();
    $newTable1.children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").get(1).remove();
    $newTable1.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").get(1).remove();
    $newTable2.children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").get(2).remove();
    $newTable2.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").get(2).remove();
    $newTable2.children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").get(0).remove();
    $newTable2.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").get(0).remove();
    $newTable3.children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").get(1).remove();
    $newTable3.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").get(1).remove();
    $newTable3.children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").get(0).remove();
    $newTable3.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").get(0).remove();
    $table.remove();
}

//Split table
var tablelist = $("table");
$.each(tablelist, function(index,value){
    if ( $(this).children("tbody").children("tr").children("th").length == 3 && $(this).children("tbody").children("tr").length == 2 && $(this).children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").length == 3) {
        jqsplit($(this), 1);
        //Don't want to do the below because some pages have several matching tables
        //return false;
    }
});
```