# Split XML table horizontally

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file having a table. I am using XSLT version 1.0. I need to split the table after a specific number of rows(Example after 7 rows). The next page should have the same headers and the data should continue.

Figure:
1. [Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXvJK.png)
2. [Table Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8TBu.png)

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A4</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5<PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A10</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A10</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A11</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A11</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A12</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:param name="prowLimit" select="10"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vartable" select="/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TABLE/ROW">
    <xsl:if test="position() mod $prowLimit = 7">

      <TBODY>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$vartable/@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::ROW[not(position() > $prowLimit )]"/>
      </TBODY>


    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A4</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5<PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>

<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A10</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A10</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A11</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A11</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A12</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

But the thing is I am not sure if the desired output is correct since I am not sure if it follows the XML hierarchy. I am going by the final result to be achieved as shown in the figures.

I used the concept provided by Dimitre Novatchev in [Split large table into several smaller tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739105/split-large-table-into-several-smaller-tables). I am getting XML parser error to maintain the structure of the XML with my XML.

How can I modify the XSLT so that I can get the output shown in the "Table Transform" figure?

Comment: Both of your table links point to the same image.

Comment: Thanks Tim, updated the figure.

Comment: Please post (1) a **complete** XML and (2) the expected result **as code**.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, I have updated the post.

Comment: Your input XML is missing a closing `</TABLE>` tag. Is this just a problem with your question, or is your actual XML also missing it (which could account for the XML parser error you mention)? It would actually help alot if you could state exactly what error you are getting. Thank you.

Comment: Your XML is still not well formed; in particular, the `TGROUP` element has no closing tag. This fault is repeated in your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/TABLE">
    <xsl:variable name="head" select="TGROUP/COLSPEC | TGROUP/THEAD" />
    <xsl:for-each select="TGROUP/TBODY/ROW[position() mod 7 = 1]">
        <TABLE>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::TABLE/@*"/>
            <TGROUP>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::TGROUP/@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$head"/>
                <TBODY>
                    <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::ROW[position() &lt; 7]"/>
                </TBODY>
            </TGROUP>
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
  <TGROUP COLS="3">
    <COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
    <COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
    <COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
    <THEAD>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>
            <EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS>
          </PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>
            <EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS>
          </PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>
            <EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS>
          </PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>B</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>C</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A1</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>B1</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A2</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>B2</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A4</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A5</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A5</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A6</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A6</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A7</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A7</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A8</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A8</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A9</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A9</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A10</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A10</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A11</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A11</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
          <PARA>A12</PARA>
        </ENTRY>
      </ROW>
    </TBODY>
  </TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
   <TGROUP COLS="3">
      <COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
      <COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
      <COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
      <THEAD>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>
                  <EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS>
               </PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>
                  <EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS>
               </PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>
                  <EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS>
               </PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
      </THEAD>
      <TBODY>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>B</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>C</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A1</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>B1</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A2</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>B2</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A4</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A5</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A5</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A6</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A6</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A7</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A7</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A8</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
      </TBODY>
   </TGROUP>
</TABLE>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
   <TGROUP COLS="3">
      <COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
      <COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
      <COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
      <THEAD>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>
                  <EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS>
               </PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>
                  <EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS>
               </PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>
                  <EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS>
               </PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
      </THEAD>
      <TBODY>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A8</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A9</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A9</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A10</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A10</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A11</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
         <ROW>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A11</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
            <ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">
               <PARA>A12</PARA>
            </ENTRY>
         </ROW>
      </TBODY>
   </TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

Note that the output is not well-formed XML because it does not have a single root element.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I modified the post. But somehow I am unable to split when applied to my XML

Comment: I am not getting the second split in the table

Comment: @ShravanVishwanathan I have modified my answer to fit the change in TGROUP. Note that your input XML is still flawed: you have an unclosed PARA element.

Comment: Still no split.. :( I checked twice the structure of XML is fine but no split.

Comment: @ShravanVishwanathan Does it work for you with my input?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the output with your XML but I don't know what is wrong with my XML?

Comment: @ShravanVishwanathan I have told you what's wrong with the XMLs you posted. If you're using another XML, then I don't know what's wrong with it, because I cannot see it.

Comment: Thanks. :) The answer was useful!